# Make menu keep its css attribute after redirection to other page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hyperlink, css

I made an accordion menu on Wordpress page. Parent of sub-menu has class "dropdown".

CSS

```
.dropdown .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown {
     list-style-type: square;
}
```

JQ

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


     jQuery('#menu-produkty_menu .dropdown a').click(function(e){
          if (jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').hide();
          } else {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').show();
          };
     });
});
```

Sub-menu is  and contains

with hyperlink .
It works fine, but whenever i click on any hyperlink from sub-menu it redirects me to other page so it gets to the basic state => all sub-menus hidden. I want sub-menu to keep opened/closed after redirection. I have never worked with database/cookie etc. so I have no idea where to start. How do I achieve that css attribe keeps changed in all pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to do this by adding a class instead of changing the css attribute
eg

```html
<li class="submenu active">title</li>
```

After changing this you can add this "active" class in your php file generating your menu.

Could you provide some html code of your accordion menu or better a url of the page?

**Upate:**
After looking more carefully i discovered you dont need to edit any php file. The only thing you need to do is toggle the .current-menu-ancestor class for the selected li. Check the fiddle again.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy2v48to/1/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, with url there is a problem, because it's on localhost yet. I coppied ul (menu) here: http://pastebin.com/N19TdNW9 and I have never worked with php either, I need a help with it. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I added the script you need above to add an active class to your submenu. 
You need to find your file that creates your menu and tweak it a little. Is it a plugin? Is it possible to post the php code that creates the menu?

Comment: This might be a problem, it's modified just by a theme (Resposive) and I seached for a php file and couldn't find it, maybe I had the wrong key words (my key words were div casses), but at Appearance >> Widgets >> Main Sidebar it says: "sidebar.php" so I copied it here for you. http://pastebin.com/d51zhC9V

Comment: Check the new update above. I edited the fiddle, commit the changes  and you are ready to go!

Comment: It's almost perfect! I kept the original js script and just added the css you gave me and it works fine. "jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('current-menu-ancestor');" makes some difficulties (script doesn't work at all). How would I achieve having multiple sub-menus opened after redirection? Thank you for help!

Comment: The script works in the fiddle i posted. Please check the differences, its the right answer. As for the multiple sub menus you must be more specific.

Comment: The script works fine, my fault, sorry. I want all opened sub-menus to keep opened. This should be the output after clicking on a hyperlink http://oi59.tinypic.com/r1a5o8.jpg . Spot the "Hydraulika" & "Kondenzacne kotly" sub-menus.

Comment: As you can understand there is a concept problem with this. There can be only one selected category for each page.
Maybe you need to accept the answer if you are ok with the progress so far or change the original question :)

Comment: Yes, i totally accept the answer and I'm so grateful for your help. Thank you once again!!